# create a multiple Mainwindow in QT

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8

Thank you for going through this post. I have searched forums,blogs and SO, but could not get what I actually need.

I am experimenting on how to display multiple mainwindows. I am using a embedded hardware board. I have successfully ported QT lib on to it.

I have written a small program.

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow text_plane;
        text_plane.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
        text_plane.setStyleSheet("background-color: Black;");
        text_plane.show();
        a.exec();
        return a.exec();
}
```

The above code displays one window only. 
Even if I create a Mainwindow w1 after  text_plane.show() like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

            QApplication a(argc, argv);
            MainWindow text_plane,w1;
            text_plane.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
            text_plane.setStyleSheet("background-color: Black;");
            text_plane.show();

            w1.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
            w1.setStyleSheet("background-color: Yellow;");
            w1.show();

            a.exec();
            return a.exec();
    }
```

Now only the w1 window is shown. What about the text_plane window ?? how to get that back.

Can anyone help me out here to make this understand.
Thank you

Comment: Remove `a.exec()`, `return a.exec()` is enough. This code display 2 main window. Are you sure you have only one? Windows have equally geometry position, check it.

Comment: Ok I will remove a.exec(). Yes the window have equally geometry position.

Comment: So try to set them different positions just like Amartel suggested below

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I wonder, what are you trying to achieve here:

```
a.exec();
return a.exec();
```

You need to call this method only once, you know.

Second of all, both of your windows are shown (you can see it in a taskbar), but, since you set `Qt::FramelessWindowHint`, one of them is drawn on top of the other. You can split them by using `move` (or something like it):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w, w1;
    w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    w.setStyleSheet("background-color: Black;");
    w.show();
    w1.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
    w1.setStyleSheet("background-color: Yellow;");
    w1.show();

    w.move(0, 0);
    w1.move(100, 100);

    return app.exec();
}
```